# What is the difference between extraction via $ and @ in R?

Tags: r

I wonder what is the difference between the "component/slot extraction" (via `?Syntax`) operators `$` (dollar sign) and `@` (at symbol) in R.

Here's an example with `$`:

```
yo=data.frame(c(1:10), c(rnorm(10,0,1)))
yo$c.1.10.
```

prints:

```
 [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
```

```
yo@c.1.10.
Error: trying to get slot "c.1.10." from an object (class "data.frame") that is not an S4 object
```

Here's an example with `@`:

```
setClass("track", representation(x="numeric", y="numeric"))
myTrack <- new("track", x = -4:4, y = exp(-4:4))
myTrack@x
```

prints:

```
[1] -4 -3 -2 -1  0  1  2  3  4
```

```
myTrack$x
Error in myTrack$x : $ operator not defined for this S4 class
```

In either case, why does one work and not the other?

Another example is the following from the `SoDA` package in R, in the function `geoXY`:

```
library(SoDA)
xy <- geoXY(gpsObject1@latitude, gpsObject1@longitude, unit = 1000)
plot(xy[,1], xy[,2], asp = 1)
```

Comment: @ is specifically for S4 objects.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I don't see anything in the [R Language defenition](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-lang.html#Indexing) about this (via [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1169456/in-r-what-is-the-difference-between-the-and-notations-for-accessing-the) question),

But the difference is basically: `@` is for S4 objects, `$` is for lists (including many S3 objects).

That may be a bit abstract, so if you're wondering about what to use for a given object, just look at `str`, e.g.:

```
str(yo)
# 'data.frame': 10 obs. of  2 variables:
#  $ c.1.10.           : int  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
#  $ c.rnorm.10..0..1..: num  -0.536 -0.453 -0.599 1.134 -2.259 ...
```

We can see `$` here, so `$` is what to use.

Alternatively,

```
str(myTrack)
# Formal class 'track' [package ".GlobalEnv"] with 2 slots
#   ..@ x: int [1:9] -4 -3 -2 -1 0 1 2 3 4
#   ..@ y: num [1:9] 0.0183 0.0498 0.1353 0.3679 1 ...
```

Here, we see `@`, so `@` is what to use.

This can get even more confusing when an S4 object has a list in one of its slots (what comes to mind first for me is a `SpatialPolygonsDataFrame`, where a column in the `data` slot can be accessed via `spdf@data$column`)

Perhaps see also `?slot` which gives a bit more detail as relates to `@`, `?isS4` for an alternative to `str` to tell you whether `@` can be expected to work with an object, or the [Chapter of Hadley Wickham's book on S4 objects](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/S4.html) for more on S4 in general.

Comment: ...although any well-designed S4 class should probably have methods to access the data contained in the class and users should not have to rely on slot names, but this is arguable...